# Neo4J cypher query do not return results in some situations

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have a query in Neo4j to calculate the path with the lowest transition cost between items. In my case I know exactly what are the types of elements to go including the depth .. here's an example:

**MATCH path = (n0: TermOccurrence) - [: CONNECTS] -> (n1: TermOccurrence) - [: CONNECTS] -> (n2: TermOccurrence) - [: CONNECTS] -> (n3: TermOccurrence) WHERE n0.termName = ' n 'AND n1.termName =' a 'AND n2.termName =' x 'AND n3.termName =' e 'RETURN path AS shortestPath, REDUCE (cost = 0, r in RELATIONSHIPS (path) | cost + r.transitionCost) AS totalCost ORDER BY totalCost ASC LIMIT 1**

In this case as a result of the query I get the lowest cost path correctly however when I change the values ​​of the termName fields from 'n' 'a' 'x' 'e' to 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a 'the result is empty ... I suspect cypher is not accepting duplicate relationships in the traversal path ... Has anyone been through something similar? My db is organized as follows:

TermOccurrence -> [: Connects] -> TermOccurrence

Thanks                    Enzo

Comment: I think you need to tell us more about your data. I would say if running that cypher does not return anything, it means there's no such a path `n-->a-->n-->a`. If you show a sample of the data you have, we might be able to help more.

Comment: Ok ! this is my path when i query for the string 'n' 'a' 'x' 'e' : 
[naxe img][1]

This is my path when i query for the string 'n' 'a' 'n' 'e' :
[name img][2]

And finally when i query for the string 'n' 'a' 'n' 'a'
[nana img][3]

I think this is happening because n->a relationship occurs more than one time on path but in my model this is perfectly normal... What I don't know is if there is a way around this restriction with neo4j...



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/psmDc.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHNkw.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuZNB.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! this is my path when i query for the string 'n' 'a' 'x' 'e' : 
[naxe img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psmDc.png)

This is my path when i query for the string 'n' 'a' 'n' 'e' :
[name img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHNkw.png)

And finally when i query for the string 'n' 'a' 'n' 'a'
[nana img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuZNB.png)

I think this is happening because n->a relationship occurs more than one time on path but in my model this is perfectly normal... What I don't know is if there is a way around this restriction with neo4j...